# I've submitted an app for the software center, but it's status says "Draft". What does this mean? Do I need to do something still?

Tags: software-center, package-management

I created a common network program.

I think that it's very useful for users that use internet.

So I uploaded it at https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/apps as you look at following picture.

[image]

And it's status is "Draft".

What does that mean, is there some action I need to take?

Comment: Probably it would have been better to create a PPA on Launchpad. However your software will not show up in Software Center unless the PPA is added to Software Sources.

Comment: You might be interested in this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/developer-portal/+bug/1078883

Comment: oh, Also I uploaded to launchpad's ppa as you say when I uploaded to https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO Draft status = Waiting to be reviewed. You may get better answers on this particular issue by visiting your fellow developers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Draft+status)

You may also be interested in [this](http://developer.ubuntu.com/2014/04/improvements-to-the-app-submission-process/)